# How to save R output data to a text file

Tags: r, rstudio, tesseract

Hope your doing well.

My question might have answered by someone else but as I couldn't able to find related answer so I'm writing a post here.

## Question

How to save R output to a text file.

I've extracted data from scanned PDF using R but my out put is in console and I want to save that as a text file. If you have any suggestions please let me know.

My code as follows

```
library (tesseract)
filename= 'my_file.pdf'
file <- pdftools::pdf_convert(filename, dpi =600)
text<- tesseract::ocr(file)
Cat(text)
```

How to save cat(text) to a text file

Thanks

## how to split below data any idea

```
  Xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx x [2 XXXX $123.45 10.1000 $10.20
```

First split has to be [2 and then spaces there after

Comment: `cat` has a `file` argument: `cat(text, file = "myfile.txt")`.

Comment: Thanks for quick response...

Comment: Could you please help me with split the data

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As  Stéphane Laurent noted, you can save the output with

```
cat(text, file = "myfile.txt")
```

If you want to create a dataframe, you could use the text object directly. For example:

```
df <- data.frame("text" = text)
```

Alternatively, if you want to save your file and then read it in, I would propose you choose a file format which is more suited for storing tables. I.e. csv.

```
write.csv(text, file = "text.csv", row.names = FALSE)

df <- read.csv("text.csv")
```

Comment: df <- data.frame("output.txt") not working, so I've to make it as df=readLines("output.txt")..... Do you have any idea how to split data in R...

Comment: Please, do yourself a favor and look into the write_csv() or save() functions to save your data as .csv or .rda format respectively. If you really need to split strings apart look into the stringr package or search on SO. This task has been discussed here 1000 times.