# Export into text, problem with html special characters

Tags: r, string, special-characters, r-rio

I am trying to export parts of dataframe in r into .txt file, using `rio::export`
the exported part is a text string that contains some characters as `>, ≥ and "`, some of these show in the text file as `&lt;   &quot;   or   &gt;` which is not what I need ( I want them to transfer into the text as greater than or less than, etc...).
when I looked these up online, I found these to be "html special characters" but I could not find a solution. I believe it has something to do with the encoding. is there a way to fix that by adding arguments to `rio::export` or do you suggest using other package?

I am using the code:

`rio::export(df, "df.txt")`

I also tried the following from this question but still gives the same problem
[How to save R output data to a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59153393/how-to-save-r-output-data-to-a-text-file)

`cat(df$text, file = "myfile.txt")` where df$text is the column that has the items I want to export.

Comment: I created the following tibble and it worked just fine with me. It exported them the way they are written. I am using a Mac.`df <- tibble(
  text_1 = "hello there, 5 > 4",
  text_2 = "print 5 if 5 ≥ value"
)


rio::export(df,"1.txt")`

Comment: @Moh thanks for replying. I tried to make a reproducible example but I found that it worded too. but I still have problems with my data, for example "(24.8 vs 31.7 and 52.4 minutes, respectively; P < 0.001)." exports as "(24.8 vs 31.7 and 52.4 minutes, respectively; P &lt; 0.001). "

Comment: hello @ Bahi8482. I tried the text you have just shared and it worked just fine with me. No `&lt` in the output. Have you tried to read the file back to R and see how it looks. also, have you tried to open the exported text file with different text editors.

Comment: @Moh The error still happens when I import the file to r and export again! actually I was working on rstudio cloud but when I tried on the installed version, I do not see the error anymore!